# How to update an element in a redux/vuex store in O(1)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, redux, vuex

How do you usually update an element(hash) in a list in the store (redux, vuex) in O(1)?

I need the order of the elements, it's important (I can add/remove elements from the list). I will update elements on each millisecond, so a lot of updates will be made.

My question is, it's very bad to save the index of the element as a property of the element? Or if the list has 500-1000 elements, it's ok to use `.find` by Id for example?

Answer (score 3):

Normalize your store shape with two properties

- Map of id to entity
- List of ids in the required order.

  `{
      byId : {
          "post1" : {
              id : "post1",
              author : "user1",
              body : "......",
              comments : ["comment1", "comment2"]
          },
          "post2" : {
              id : "post2",
              author : "user2",
              body : "......",
              comments : ["comment3", "comment4", "comment5"]
          }
      },
      allIds : ["post1", "post2"]
  }`

With this structure, you can update a particular entity in O(1) complexity, and also retrieve the entities in the order of insertion by iterating `allIds`.

More information can be found [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape)

Comment: Thanks, nice solution!